# Перенос значений столбца xlsx файла в строку программы через код C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel

Есть два xlsx файла и программа, отправляющая результаты (в данном случае это значения столбца). Моя задача: взять значения из столбца (то есть, ctrl c, ctrl v) и поместить их в строчку, которая находится в программе. Перед запуском самой программы, данной строчки нету, тк находимся на главном экране. Нужно сначала нажать на кнопку "Отчет" и нас перенесет на страницу, где есть строка, куда нужно поместить данные из таблицы. Если разбить это все на задачи, будет выглядеть так:

1. Открыть xlsx файл
2. Скопировать значения столбца
3. Открыть программу
4. Перейти на вкладку "Отчет"
5. Поместить значения в строчку
6. Нажать на кнопку "Отправить"

Из всего этого есть только метод открытия программы:

---

> static void OpenProgramm()
> {
> Process.Start("D:\Podacha\Temp.exe");
> }

---

Comment: Ничего не понятно, особенно "Чтобы дойти до этого поля, нужно кликнуть по кнопке "Отчет", где хранится это поле." Какое поле, какой отчет, где это все лежит, кто и куда должен нажимать и что происходить. Провернуть клик в программе? Какой, вашей, в Excel или где? Пожалуйста, напишите нормально то, что вы хотите, чтобы можно было дать нормальный ответ, не пишите ответ в комментариях, поправляйте сам вопрос.

Comment: @OwDafuq, сейчас должно выглядеть попонятнее.

Comment: Может быть вам нужна программа для записи/запуска макросов, например [Mouse Recorder Pro 2](https://nemex-studios.com/software/3D%20Picture%20Viewer%201.3)? И кнопки нажимает, и клавиши, и программировать ничего не нужно, и объяснять что и где Вам нужно скопировать/запустить/вставить...

Comment: @XelaNimed, вариант решения хороший, думаю попробую его, но желательно именно код, тк я дописал почти программу и остался только этот момент с переносом данных из xlsx файла

Answer (score 1):

Вам предстоит знакомство с WinApi. Доку ищите на сайте Microsoft и на pinvoke.net.

Алгоритм будет такой:

1. Найдём окно по имени.
2. Найдём в этом окне нужную кнопку
3. Кликнем на неё.
4. Ищем вкладку, кликаем на неё
5. Ищем строку, вставляем в неё данные
6. Ищем кнопку "Отправить" и кликаем на неё.

Идентификаторы объектов ищем через инструмент Spy++ из состава Visual Studio.

Пример того, как найти приложение и кликнуть на кнопку: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/clicking-a-button-in-another-application/

Для вставки текста потребуется метод SendDlgItemMessage.